# Scroll horizontal according to the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an iframe with a large width.

This iframe has a few hours in it.

I need a code where the screen follow this iframe according to the current time.

For example, if you are 12:00, the screen needs to follow this iframe, since use "commercial" hours (9:00 am - 18:00 pm)

I made using this method MacGyver.

I'm sure that is not the best way, but it worked ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container { 
                width:100%; height:800px; margin:auto; 
            }
            #outerdiv {
                width:100%;
                height:246px;
                position:relative;
            }
            #tabela {
                position:absolute;
                left:-100px;
                width:2500px;
                height:800px;
            }
        </style>
        <link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dash.css">
        <?php
            include("codigos/config.php"); 
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <input type='button' class='leftArrow' value='Esquerda'>
            <input type='button' class='rightArrow' value='Direita'>
            <script>
                now = new Date;
                document.write (now.getHours()); 
            </script>
            <div id="outerdiv"> 
                <iframe src="tabelateste.php" id="tabela" name="tabela" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
            </div>
            <script> 
                if (new Date().getHours() <= 9) {
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "0px"
                } else if(new Date().getHours() == 10){
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-120px"
                } else if(new Date().getHours() == 11){
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-240px"
                } else if(new Date().getHours() == 12){
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-360px"
                } else if(new Date().getHours() == 13){
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-480px"
                } else if(new Date().getHours() == 14){
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-600px"
                } else if(new Date().getHours() == 15){
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-720px"
                } else if(new Date().getHours() == 16){
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-840px"
                } else if(new Date().getHours() == 17){
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-960px"
                } else if(new Date().getHours() >= 18){
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-1100px"
                }  
                
                $(".leftArrow").click(function () { 
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "0px"
                });
                $(".rightArrow").click(function () { 
                    document.getElementById("tabela").style.left = "-1100px"
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I do not have anything.
I do not have much knowledge with javascript or jquery, googled enough but found nothing like what I need.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "write code for me" service. You need to start by yourself and if you have trouble, you can ask here specific question. Please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I do not know the correct terms to search, this is the big problem.
I know it seems I'm trying everything ready, but if anyone knows where I can get, this has help me

Comment: Did you create the iframe already? Do you have **any** piece of code?!

Comment: Don't forget that if you want to nutify a user just mention him in your comment (Like @MoshFeu)

Comment: It seems to work well [demo](http://output.jsbin.com/samodep), what is the problem?